# How to debug QtWebEngine sandboxing

Tags: macos, qt6, qtwebengine

we have an app that renders some off-line files via QtWebEngine. The app is multiplatform.
Yet recently when upgrading to Qt6 on MacOS the rendering stopped working.

If I turn of the QtWebEngine sandboxing, it works. The app does not use apple sandboxing.

I run out of ideas how to debug what is wrong.

I run all kinds of debug outputs.

I get
`sandbox initialization failed: empty subpath pattern?`

Is there something that changed from Qt5-Qt6? How to debug this? Or how to have non-empty subpath pattern?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same situation.pyqt6.5.0, pyinstaller5.1
My windows is OK.
But my mac(both m1 and intel) both not.
When I add
os.environ['QTWEBENGINE_DISABLE_SANDBOX']='1'
my program will log
malloc: Incorrect checksum for freed object 0x1538c0bc0: probably modified after being freed.
malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

when I do not
the screen will blank and show
sandbox initialization failed: empty subpath pattern
sandbox initialization failed: empty subpath pattern

I don't know how to fix it

Comment: In C++ we use `qputenv( "QTWEBENGINE_CHROMIUM_FLAGS", qgetenv( "QTWEBENGINE_CHROMIUM_FLAGS" ) + " --no-sandbox" );`
That kind of helps... As our app use webengine only to load static local files and render them to user. 
But we would like to do better.